# Python2.7: How to create a new StreamHandler without losing the module name on each output line?

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, python-logging

I want to replace the default `StreamHandler`, to redirect output to a different stream. However, when I create a new `StreamHandler`, the module name no longer appears in logging output:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level = logging.INFO)

LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)


for handler in logging.getLogger().handlers:
    logging.getLogger().removeHandler(handler)
logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())

# without the above 3 lines:  INFO:__main__:hello
# with   the above 3 lines:  hello


LOG.info('hello')
```

Is it possible to create a new `StreamHandler` without losing the module name on each output line?

Comment: You need to attach a Formatter.

Comment: @Klaus Yeah, just figured that out the second you posted that... See my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Copy the formatter from the old handler to the new one:

```
h, = logging.getLogger().handlers
logging.getLogger().removeHandler(h)
logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
logging.getLogger().handlers[0].setFormatter(h.formatter)
```